# Path to external HD in mame config file

Tags: paths, mame

I'm trying to set the path to the rom directory in mame to an external HD, the line in mame.ini config is

```
rompath                  $HOME/mame/roms
```

this works for the roms in the HD but when I try to add the path to the HD

```
rompath                  $HOME/mame/roms;/media/nestor/TOSHIBA\ EXT/mame/roms
```

I don't get any results. I've tried  '/media/nestor/TOSHIBA EXT/mame/roms' also with "" or with the HD path alone.

Is there another path name for this HD I could be trying? There's nothing in mnt

This is obviously not a major problem I'll end up copying the roms to the HD folder but it's annoying I can't even get such a basic task done in linux :)

Comment: Have you checked that all the destinations have the same case? Also check that the `mame` folder is not `.mame`. Otherwise try `df -h` in the terminal, which should say where your external drive is mounted, then you can double check the path is correct.

Comment: Yes there is a .mame directory also, the config file was in /etc/mame but I used mame cc to autogenerate a config file in .mame, interestingly it found the roms directory in the external HD but mame is still unable to access those games when run. There's something screwy with my PC's automount (I need to re-log in for it to kick in) so it might be related to that

Comment: Could be permissions in the external drive maybe?

Comment: No, the external's permissions are more open than the home directory, tried changing the permissions for "enclosed files" (Does that mean .zip files like the roms? I assume so) but no difference.